# Airflow DAG AutoRestart

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Can we have a feature other than

```
retries
```

in airflow, to automatically restart the dag at the end of the day,  if it fails for the given retries?

I tried to restart the task after its failure, I tried for **retries** which we can give it in airflow config. But I want to restart the dag automatically, without doing it manually by clearing the dag or task , if it get failed.